# How can I backup my cpanel home directory to another cpanel host?

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel

I have a laravel php website on Godaddy cpanel, and new host with different domain on Godaddy.
I want anyway to transfer my website into my new host.

i tried to compress the whole project into one zip file to download and upload it to the new host but i had limitations to the disk quota i couldn't compress it because it will exceed the disk quota

if there is someway to just backup the whole project to the new host that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, since backing-up your project exceeds your maximum quota - you are out of luck in terms of Cpanel getting the job done.

It could be worth using FTP - if you have the details to connect to your package.

Once connected via FTP, you can simply download the entire directory from root - typically public_html or http_docs and then upload them to your new location.

Comment: yeah, i can do that but i was thinking there is any automatic way to send the backup i mean server to server not me included

Comment: @abdelhamiedmostafa I have not used the GoDaddy cPanel - but no, I doubt this is possible. It could be worth contacting GoDaddy support in order to see if they are able to facilitate a transfer.